# How can I get Eclipse IDE to default to "Selected lines" in the Find/Replace dialogue when multiple lines are selected?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

When working in Eclipse and hitting Ctrl+F with lines of code selected, the default behavior I expect is for the Find/Replace dialogue to open with the "Selected lines" option and, perhaps, either buffer contents or a previous search query in the "Find" prompt. On my home machine, what happens instead is the entire selection gets automatically copied to the "Find" prompt and Scope is reset to "All" instead of "Selected lines" every time.

I somehow *do* have this working by default on my work machine: "Selected Lines" scope option is chosen automatically when more than one line is selected in the editor.

Possibly unrelated: I do have CDT installed and I work mostly with C++ in Eclipse. Home machine is running Ubuntu 18.10, work machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried:

- Re-downloading Eclipse, reinstalling CDT & cmake4eclipse
- Changing to a new Workspace in Eclipse (without copying settings)
- Searching high and low online for recipes on how to control this.

How do I change the IDE at home to the desired "Selected Lines" behavior?

[Edit 1 hour later]: I am now almost convinced the issue has to do with the Ubuntu version somehow. I'm running 18.04 on my Laptop (same as my work computer) and I just upgraded CDT & Eclipse Platform to latest stable versions (9.7 and 4.11/2019-03, respectively), which I have everywhere else. The new "wrong" behavior didn't appear. I will also start a thread on the Eclipse forums or perhaps even open a bug report. I don't want to reinstall the whole system or downgrade it (slim chance of success) just to get this back; if it's an Eclipse bug, I'd rather work on fixing it.

[Edit 2 days later] The bug did not manifest on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10. I still have no idea what was different on the 'culprit' machine. I ended up wiping the drive and reinstalling 18.04 on the same machine and the problem went away.

Comment: You could try reading the `initFindStringFromSelection` in the source of the dialog (`org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindReplaceDialog`), this seems to be the code that decides on the settings.

Comment: _The new "wrong" behavior didn't appear._ On which platform and which Eclipse version the _Selected Lines_ are not(!) preselected if multiple lines are selected in the current editor and where the behavior is as expected? Please note, that this might also be related to the current editor.

Comment: @howlger On all systems I have 4.11/2019-03. It did "appear", in a sense, or it doesn't appear to be anything I did: I re-downloaded the whole IDE and made a fresh workspace for it, only to find the same regressed behavior. The only difference I can see is Ubuntu 18.10 (bad behavior) vs Ubuntu 18.04 (good behavior). It also doesn't appear to be related to the current editor (tried with plain text editor, CMake editor, CDT editor, etc.)

Comment: @GregKramida I see. Could you please try `export SWT_GTK3=0` before running Eclipse in the terminal?

Comment: @howlger thank you, I just tried, unfortunately the results are the same as before.

Comment: @GregKramida Thanks for [reporting it to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546170).